# google calendar api with php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

i need to integrate google calendar API to show the logged in users google calendar in my php website , with the all the same functions it have in the google calendar , there is any possible way to do this? 
currently am working with this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/
so kindly let me know your suggestions .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out some links,

[Calendar API](http://www.w3.org/TR/calendar-api/#usage-example)

[How to Access Google Calendar With Php Using Google API](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Google-Calendar-With-PHP-Using-Google-API)

[Google APIs Client Library for Php](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/Samples)

[Integrate your Php application with Google Calendar](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/)

[Google Calendar API : PHP](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/04/26/howto-google-calendar-api-php/)

[Adding/Deleting Events with the Google Calendar API](http://mark.biek.org/blog/2010/07/addingdeleting-events-with-the-google-calendar-api/)

[add-2-google-cal](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7420-PHP-Generate-links-to-add-events-to-Google-Calendar.html)

[New JSON format for the Google Calendar API](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2010/09/new-json-format-for-google-calendar-api.html)

may help you.

Comment: @jothikannan I think its enough to get your answer.

Comment: hi Amin thanks for your answer, i will check it and let you know about it

Comment: Hi, Amin thanks for the links they all helping me more , and am re coding them as how i want.

Comment: Is it possible to use google calendar api with custom styling as the custom site where calendar is being integrated?

Comment: Unfortunately most of the links in this answer are either unavailable or out-of-date.