# Google Calendar Yes/Maybe/No From PHP backend (google-calendar Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

First I would Like to explain what my current condition is. I am able to create and get Google Calendar Event Id. The thing I want to do is create a checkbox on my site. When my client/attendees(google calendar attendees) click that checkbox then they should be attending(I mean action same as clicking Yes on event of a  Google Calendar event when attendees opens their google calendar).

Actual result I want is to perform Yes action of Google Calendar From php Backend from my site.

Code:

//Creating Google Calendar Event And storing ID 
//inputs are taken from $request from laravel Route

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
    {
        // $client= new Google_Client();
        // $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

        $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(array('curl' => array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false)));
        $client->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);
        $this->client = $client;
        // print_r($_SESSION); die();
        $this->client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
            'summary' => $title,
            'description' => $notes,
            'colorId' => 2,
            'start' => array(
                'dateTime' => $start_date,
            ),
            'end' => array(
              'dateTime' => $final_date,
            ),
            'attendees' => $datalist,
            'guestsCanInviteOthers' => FALSE,
            'visibility' => "private",

            'reminders' => array(
                'useDefault' => FALSE,
                'overrides' => array(
                    array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                    array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
                ),
            ),
        ));
        $params = [ "sendNotifications" => "TRUE" ];
        $results = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event,$params);
        $activity->eventId=$result->id; //stored in database activity table
        if (!$results) 
        {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong']);
        }
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Event Created']);
    }
```

Comment: You need to add some code with your description.

Comment: This will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889040/google-calendar-api-with-php

Comment: Hello Sir, I am already Able to create,list,modify,delete event in Google Calendar, But now i want to perform Yes,No, or Maybe Action As we do from Google Calendar from Backend Laravel